# How to implement @NotNull validation on json dtos?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

**Post Edit**: I have tried with a simple rest api hello world project with validating input here: https://github.com/abidinberkay/testQuestion still I can't find where I am doing smth wrong.

I have a dto class whose fields are marked with **@NotNull**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class UserCreateRequest {

    @NotNull
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String surname;

    @NotNull
    private String job;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

And I am using this dto in a controler method with **@Valid** annotation

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public UserCreateResponse createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserCreateRequest userDto) {
        return userService.createUser(userDto);
    }

}
```

Whenever I send post request with null fields, it is still creating user with null values so @NotNull or @NotBlank validations are not working. How can I be sure that the request json will have these fields as specified in request class ?

Here is my sample postman request body(as you see only userName exists and all others are null):

```
{
    "userName" : "nnnnn"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have just realised that the **@Valid** does nothing just alone. I have added **BindingResult** as parameter to controller method and handled the problem as follows.

```
@PostMapping
    public UserCreateResponse createUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserCreateRequest userDto, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
        else {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Weird thing is that many examples on web, youtube etc. working normally but this problem happened to me. Probably it is something related to spring version.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but you just have to annotate your controller class with [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) to enable the validations:

```java
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {
    …
}
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation):

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation.

Comment: still not working and it is accepting all requests. Do I need to create a bean with @Configuration annotation or smth like this ?